# SCSS files compile to CSS file on server side

Tags: css, git, sass, gulp

I ignored .CSS files in .gitignore.
But I want that they compile on the server side that changes will be on production.
I did that, because when we(for example, two developers ) worked on the same repository, we had conflicts due to .css files.
I hope that I could explain my problem.
Do you know some ways to solve my problem?

// I want to make changes to .scss files and after they compiled to css on the server side

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. I suggest to put a step-by-step list of what you're doing (how-to-reproduce) and then specify the 2 outcomes: the one that actually happens currently and the one that you expect (and need a help to implement). The step-by-step list should contain specific actions you're doing with your the code itself and the source files. E. g. "1. changing .scss; 2. compiling .scss to .css; 3. pushing .css to remote repo 4. uploading the compiled .css to the web server from the repo".